# Nodejs OPC-UA server cannot find suitable endpoints in avaible endpoints

Tags: node.js, opc-ua

I do create an opc-ua server like this:

```
var opcOptions = {
        hostname: options.opcHost || "127.0.0.1",
        port: options.opcPort || 4334,
        resourcePath: options.opcName || "opcua",
        buildInfo: {
            productName: "OPCUA",
            buildNumber: "0.1",
            buildDate: new Date()
        }
    }

    var server = new opcua.OPCUAServer(opcOptions);
    server.start(function (err) {
        console.log("OPC Server is now available at: " + endpointUrl + " ( press CTRL+C to stop)");
    })
```

And after the console will print that the OPC Server is avaible at `opc.tcp://localhost:4334/opcua`
I get following error/info message every time an opc-ua session from a client is created to my server:

```
10:45:21.095Z :opcua_server                  :443   Cannot find suitable endpoints in available endpoints. endpointUri = opc.tcp://192.168.0.10:4334/opcua
```

The OPC-UA client does work without problems.

I did search for this message but I only found that other got this message when connecting to an opc server but I don't use any client here.

Any idea on how to prevent this message from showing up?